# Maven resolver from pom.xml, Shrinkwrap

Tags: java, maven, integration-testing, shrinkwrap

In tests when I set a full path to pom.xml, everything works fine:

```
{code}
File[] files = Maven.resolver().loadPomFromFile("/full/system/path/pom.xml").importDependencies(ScopeType.TEST, ScopeType.PROVIDED).resolve().withTransitivity().asFile();
{code}
```

In a lot of examples, just pom.xml is used, so I tried:

```
{code}
File[] files = Maven.resolver().loadPomFromFile("pom.xml").importDependencies(ScopeType.TEST, ScopeType.PROVIDED).resolve().withTransitivity().asFile();
{code}
```

But in this case I get exception:

```
Path to the pom.xml file must be defined and accessible
```

Same result if I try to pass ""../pom.xml". I have to include all dependencies from `pom.xml` into the war archive, that is deployed during arquillian tests, is there a workaround?
Ideally, I'd like to reuse the pom.xml that is used to build project. I don't want to have a separate pom.xml file in the "src/test/resources" folder.

**EDIT**: I've got the main idea of @baba, but instead of coping pom.xml, I've set a `basedir` property via maven resource filtering:

I've added the `tests.properties` file into `test/resources`, added a property in the file:

```
basedir=${basedir}
```

In pom.xml I've used the [http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html]

```
<build>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
```

In tests, I've loaded all dependencies:

```
ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle ("tests");
String baseDir = resourceBundle.getString("basedir");
File[] files = Maven.resolver().loadPomFromFile(baseDir + File.separator + "pom.xml").importDependencies(ScopeType.TEST, ScopeType.PROVIDED).resolve().withTransitivity().asFile();
```

Comment: Are you running on Linux?

Comment: @AndrewSmiley, yes, I am.

Comment: @Alexandr that's even better.

Answer (score 2):

You have to realize one thing first and then two other things.
Here is the first thing:

1. As soon as you are talking about relative paths in a jar and not fullpaths, you are talking (mostly) about classpath files. So you probably should take a look at [LoadPomTask](https://github.com/shrinkwrap/resolver/blob/master/impl-maven/src/main/java/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/resolver/impl/maven/task/LoadPomTask.java) which has a method

> public static LoadPomTask loadPomFromClassLoaderResource(final String
>   pathToPomResource)

Now that we realized that there is no way to avoid the classpath, we have to answer two other questions:

1. Is the pom.xml file bundled in the classpath by default (answer: yes) (where? by default-> `META-INF/maven/${groupId}/${artifactId}/pom.xml`)
2. If I am using a test framework, like surefire, does it change the classpath and is the pom.xml available at the same location at the time of the execution of the tests (answer: yes, mostly)

Suggested solution:
Since `META-iNF/MAVEN/${groupId}/${artifactId}` is subject to change, you **shouldn't have reference in your code that loads the stuff from there**. So I'd suggest you take a look at the  [maven-resources-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/). Which'd allow you to copy the pom.xml file during compilation at a location of your choosing (I'd actually recommend you copy it to two locations:

```
/src/main/resources
```

and

```
/src/test/resources
```

During the `process-resources` and the `process-test-resources` phases accordingly: [see maven-build-lifecycles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)

To sum it up:

1. You need to load the pom.xml from the classpath if you want to be using a location of type (pom.xml) and not the full path
2. You need to include the pom.xml file during the compilation phase using the maven-resources-plugin to be in your classpath